# Referencing another key with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Hey guys I have two tables in my database `youtube.artists` and `youtube.song`, and I would like the `artist` field in `youtube.song` to reference the `name` field in `youtube.artists`. The relationship looks something like this (sorry it's so big):

[image: screenshot from dbdiagram.io]

And my code looks like this currently (and side note if someone knows a better way to format this let me know, the data comes from an API in JSON format):

```py
dbAuth_cursor.execute("""
                    with ins_artist as (
                        SELECT * FROM youtube.artists WHERE youtube_id = '{0}'
                        returning artistID
                    )
                    INSERT INTO youtube.song (mattfm_id, yt_id, published, genre, title, artist, description, viewcount, duration, thumbnail)
                    VALUES ('{1}', '{2}','{3}','{4}', '{5}', (REFERENCES artistID from ins_artist), '{7}', '{8}', '{9}');
                """.format(data.artist.yt_id, str(random.randint), data.yt_id, data.published, data.genre, data.title, data.description, data.viewcount, data.duration, data.thumbnail))
```

And finally, my table definitions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE youtube.artists (
  name varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  youtube_id varchar(66) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE youtube.song (
  mattfm_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  yt_id varchar(66) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  published date,
  genre varchar(64),
  title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  artist varchar(100) REFERENCES youtube.artists (name),
  description text NOT NULL,
  viewcount bigint,
  duration int,
  thumbnail varchar(107),
  CONSTRAINT yt_author FOREIGN KEY(artist) REFERENCES youtube.artists(name)
);
```

When I run that I get an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "artists_name_key"` which makes sense since the artist would already have been added into `youtube.artist` but that is what I believe I want.

I tried looking around but I couldn't find anything that was specific to psycopg2, it was more general PostgreSQL commands.

I am using the [official Postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), Python 3.8.10, and [psycopg2 2.9.7](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

Comment: Can you share the table definitions please ([edit] the question and copy and paste the output of `\d name-of-table` from the psql console). Please also add the _complete_ error traceback and the code that you are actually running - the SQL in the question is not valid. And please review [the psycopg2 docs on parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Off hand I would say you have the FK relationship between youtube.artists and youtube.song backwards.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Sorry about that, that was an oversight on my part. I have added the definitions

Comment: Why is the FK defined twice: `artist varchar(100) REFERENCES youtube.artists (name)` and `CONSTRAINT yt_author FOREIGN KEY(artist) REFERENCES youtube.artists(name)`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver to be honest I'm not totally sure. But I tried removing that second reference (and the first in another try) and had the same error

Comment: 1) This `youtube.song (mattfm_id, yt_id, published,  ... )` and this `format(data.artist.yt_id, str(random.randint), data.yt_id, data.published, ...)` don't match.  2) Update your question to show the code you are currently using.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is copy and pasted from my code base, what specific part is not matching? It looks the same to me

Comment: Compare `(mattfm_id, yt_id ...)` to `VALUES ('{1}', '{2}','{3}','{4}',  ...)` to `format(data.artist.yt_id, str(random.randint), data.yt_id ...` ) and show me how they match?